# Provide filtered data as input to plotting line strings in D3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am currently filtering my data obtained from the csv file in this manner

```
d3.csv("Viz2SampleData.csv", function(data43) 

{
 links = [];
 data43.filter(function(d,i)
  { 

    if (d3.select("#select-owner").node().value == "ALL" && d3.select("#select-contractor").node().value != "ALL" && d3.select("#select-launch").node().value == "ALL")
    {

   //   for(var i=0, len=d.length-1; i<=len; i++)
    //  {
          console.log(d.length)
        if (d3.select("#select-contractor").node().value == d.CountryOfContractor)
        {      
        return d;
        }


            ]
        })

    }



  })//closing for filter
```

Now, I wish to draw the links using the code below only for this filtered data above that has been selected based on my conditions. The code below draws the linestrings for all the rows in the CSV file without any filter. The data43 element is not getting filtered or i'm accessing it in a wrong manner

```
 links.push({
            type: "LineString",
            coordinates: [
                [ data43[i].OperatorOwnerLon, data43[i].OperatorOwnerLat ],
                [ data43[i].CountryOfContractorLon, data43[i].CountryOfContractorLat ],
                [ data43[i].lon, data43[i].lat ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure the conditions you're trying to filter on, but `filter` does not modify arrays in place. It returns a new array of items for which the filter predicate evaluates to `true`. So if you want to get filtered data items, you need to assign the results of `data43.filter()` to something; maybe even `data43` again, if you no longer care about the other results.

Also, for things that are constant, best to compute their value first, not inside the loop.

This is what I think you were trying to accomplish:

```
d3.csv("Viz2SampleData.csv", function(data43) {

  var links = [];
  var selectOwner = d3.select("#select-owner").node().value;
  var selectContractor = d3.select("#select-contractor").node().value;

  data43 = data43.filter((d,i) => {
    return (selectOwner === 'ALL') && (selectContractor === d.CountryOfContractor);
  });

  ...
```

Comment: Jonathan I cannot thank you enough. That worked like a charm :)